# Sorting list that has tuple as an element with Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list as follows.

```
[(5,), (2,), (4,), (1,), (3,), (6,), (7,), (8,)]
```

How can I sort the list to get

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

or

```
[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the list of tuples into a list of integers, then sort it:

```
thelist = [(5,), (2,), (4,), (1,), (3,), (6,), (7,), (8,)]

sortedlist = sorted([x[0] for x in thelist])

print sortedlist
```

See it on [codepad](http://codepad.org/gni0T6W6)

Comment: why not just `sorted([x[0] for x in list])`? sorted is a reserved word so maybe not best to use as a variable.

Comment: @Justine Peel: It's not a reserved word, it's just the name of a function, but the point still stands.

Comment: He also asked for reverse: `sorted([x[0] for x in list], reverse=True)`.  Also, "list" is a builtin. +1 nonetheless

Comment: @chpwn, you're right I misspoke. Not reserved, just a function.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an even more generalized answer:

```
from itertools import chain
sorted( chain.from_iterable( myList ) )
```

which can sort not only what you've asked for but also any list of arbitrary length tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```
datalist = [(5,), (2,), (4,), (1,), (3,), (6,), (7,), (8,)]
sorteddata = sorted(data for listitem in datalist for data in listitem)
reversedsorted = sorteddata[::-1]
print sorteddata
print reversedsorted

# Also
print 'With zip', sorted(zip(*datalist)[0])
```